# my goal is to send ,in side the connection string the "pc name" for Audit

Tags: sql-server

I have a connection string (SQL Server):

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

My goal is to send inside the connection string the "pc name".

This is so I can later Audit it, or to later see the information in log file from which computer the user has been connected to the SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have `Workstation ID` in the connection string. Whatever you put in there is shown in SQL Server Profiler in column `HostName`.

In my testing I found that if you do not specify `Workstation ID` in the connection string you will still get the the name of the client computer automatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;
User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;Application Name=yourpcname
```

If "yourpcname" is the name of your PC.
In SQL profiler or [login audit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175850.aspx) - capture the Application Name for a specific SQL user ID.

Note: It is recommended to use Windows authentication whenever possible.

Comment: the application name show ".net sqlclient dataprovider" this is not for me i need to see the computer name

Comment: @user554672: That is why Richard suggested setting it to "yourpcname" in the connection string (look at his answer again). ".NET SqlClient Dataprovider" is only the default-value if you don't set it otherwise in the connection string.